# How to delete uuid post in PostgreSQL 10.6?

Tags: postgresql

I can delete post in the application but not outside in psql.

example:

```
DELETE FROM post 
WHERE id = 9fe8e718-8853-4950-8c33-199e8194fde6;
```

return Syntax error !!!

```
/**
 * @var \Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface
 *
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
 */
private $id;

/*
 * Get id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to enclose the value in single quotes:

```
DELETE FROM post 
WHERE id = '9fe8e718-8853-4950-8c33-199e8194fde6';
```